# Ubuntu not dicovering "ANY" hardware?

Tags: 12.04, hardware, startup

i sodoed a code (i had copied it from a website, i dont remember which) to show "all" startup applications, without knowing the importance of "Detect-New-Hardware-On-Start-Up" Option, I unchecked it and removed it from the list, now my Touchpad, WiFi, Bluetooth, are not getting detected, i regret for messing it and help is badly/urgently needed, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a new user from the recovery mode. The command to use is `adduser desired_username sudo`.

You'll be asked for a password, and when done, run `sudo reboot`.